# Get only the updated events from google calendar using google client php api

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to sync google calendar with my website.I am using google client php api. Till now i am able to get all the events from google calendar.Is there a way to get only the updated events from google calendar.
Below is the code to get the events from google calendar

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName( $app_name ); 
$client->setDeveloperKey( $app_key ); 
$cal = new Google_Service_Calendar( $client );
$calendarId = $app_id;

$params = array(      
  'singleEvents' =>   true,
  'orderBy'      =>   'startTime',
);
$events = $cal->events->listEvents($calendarId, $params);
foreach ( $events->getItems() as $event ) {
echo $event->getSummary();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can only use `orderBy` parameter. It has a value "**updated**" that orders the events by last modification time (ascending). Here is the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).

Comment: @user5916491 thank you for responding..  i used the parameter "update" the events were sorted by last modified events.but all events are shown.I only need the events which are modified not all the events. Is there any way to do this .. ?

Comment: No, that does not work. If you modify an occurrence (event instance), then modify the whole series, you'll get all event instances with the same `updated` time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into the same feature, but apparently their public Google Calendar API does not allow that. Seems like the only way is to get the master recurring event and compare it against all event instances (field by field). I bet they have an internal API that provides that info for internal calendar synchronization.

Sorry, no PHP code, I use C# and REST API.

Answer (score 0):

In API v3 you can use param updatedMin.

```
 $datetime = \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2019-07-14 05:40:00");

 $events = $service->events->listEvents('primary', [
   "updatedMin" => $datetime->format(\DateTime::RFC3339)
 ]);
```